# GnuWin32 openssl s_client conn to WebSphere MQ server not closing at EOF, hangs

Tags: batch-file, openssl, ibm-mq, gnuwin32

I am trying to use the GnuWin32 version of OpenSSL to fetch certificates from several WebSphere MQ queue managers.  All attempts result in OpenSSL keeping the connection open until I manually hit ENTER.

I tried piping various text into the command [as per this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450120/openssl-hangs-and-does-not-exit) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985726/closing-connections-via-s-client-in-a-shell-script), but with no luck.

Ideally, OpenSSL would close the connection once the input file or piped text hit EOF.

Examples:

```
echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect qmgrhost:1414 -showcerts 

openssl s_client -connect qmgrhost:1414 -showcerts < responsefile.txt
```

The examples using the `QUIT` command appear to work in the other SO question because they are hitting an HTTP server.  Since this is WMQ in my case, the connection handshake is different and sending `QUIT` (or anything else I've tried) doesn't get it to close the connection.  I could probably feed it a giant file until the QMgr choked and killed the connection but I'm trying to be as polite as possible to the server.  The current method of supplying an ENTER from the keyboard is causing FDC dumps on each connection as it is, setting off all kinds of alarms and making the Tivoli guys mad at me.

So best case would be a string or hex value the QMgr interprets as a graceful rejection and closes the connection.  Second best case is *any* method that allows this to be scripted and we'll accept the FDC files as a cost of automating this function.

**UPDATE: 31 May 2013**
I've since moved to AIX where this works perfectly. The s_client hangs up immediately after making the connection when run in a script and piping a newline into it.  However, I'd still like to have a solution for Windows.  Does anyone know if the Cygwin version works or has the same problem?  Is it Windows signalling/POSIX issue?  Code bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this problem is related to a synchronization issue between the Batch file and the openssl.exe program. I need your collaboration in order to do some tests and report the result. Below is a Batch-JScript hybrid script for the first test. The JScript section have two parts; the first one `WScript.Stdout.WriteLine("QUIT");` is entirely equivalent to `echo QUIT` Batch command. The second part (with two lines) is similar, but it load the keyboard buffer with "QUIT" and an Enter key instead of send the string via STDOUT.

I need you to make a test with both sections of the JScript code and report the result (the double-slash `//` mark the rest of the line as comment). If we are lucky, the `openssl.exe` program will end with the `Sendkeys` method; if not, try to send a "QUIT" string via `STDOUT` and type just an Enter key with `Sendkeys`. If the `openssl.exe` program terminate before returning the desired information then the problem is almost solved, because in this case we can synchronize the sending of the Enter key until the desired information had been received from `openssl.exe`.

Save the following as a `.bat` file.  Try it, then comment out the `Wscript` line, uncomment the `WshShell` lines, and then try it again.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

:: The first line above is...
:: in Batch: a valid IF command that does nothing.
:: in JScript: a conditional compilation IF statemente that is false,
::             so this section is omitted until next "at-sign end".

@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" | openssl s_client -connect qmgrhost:1414 -showcerts 
goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

WScript.Stdout.WriteLine("QUIT");

// var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
// WshShell.SendKeys("QUIT{ENTER}");
```

You may also try with `String.fromCharCode(26)` to generate a Ctrl-Z (EOF) character, both in `WriteLine` or `Sendkeys` methods; for example:

```
WshShell.SendKeys("QUIT{ENTER}" + String.fromCharCode(26));
```

Comment: Took me a couple days of reading to determine how to run my first JScript script.  Eventually I found [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/01/15/running-jscript-in-a-cmd-file.aspx) and realized I just run it as a bat file.  Duh!  Anyway, sending `\n` with SendKeys unblocks the script.  Thanks!

Comment: @T.Rob: Thanks a lot! I apologize for the unclear instructions (I assumed you know this is a Batch .bat file)...

Comment: No problem. I needed to learn something today anyway to meet my quota.  ;-)  I honestly didn't know about this technique but I can see I'll be using it a lot from now on so it was well worth the bounty.

Comment: Yes. I don't like the JScript multi-line comment method because it is somewhat confusing and the closing `*/` may to go unnoticed! I think that my method with the `@end` delimiter is much clearer.