# How to make a batch file to run a hotkey

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

Every time I start my Windows I want to execute a hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) using a batch file and putting it in startup folder. Is that even possible? Is there a command for that?

Comment: All I found was how to run shortcuts!

Comment: 1) If you did research (successful or not), provide what you have tried in your question. 2) Your is question very unclear to me. You tagged [autohotkey], but you didn't mention it once. What role does AHK play here? Do you want to run an AHK script which sends keys? Do you want a batch file to send keys? Should AHK start the batch file or vice versa? Or do you want to create a hotkey that starts the batch file?What are you trying to achieve in general? You're giving too little info about your whole problem. Please spend more effort explaining it.

Comment: MCL has said it right.  You must "get into the spirit" of Stack Exchange.  Once you do, the site will become very valuable to you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't send keys directly from a batch file, instead you can create a VB script to send the keys and call this script from a .bat file

Put the following code to a VB script, for example sendkeys.vbs (^ is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and % is <kbd>Alt</kbd>)

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^%1"
```

Put the following code to a batch file, for example sendkeys.bat(required full path of the VB script if they are not in the same folder)

```
wscript "sendkey.vbs"
```

Finally, put sendkeys.bat to Windows startup folder.

[SendKeys in VB Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, thank you! I'm sorry for my condensed version of a problem listed above. Live and learn :)

Comment: @gVoid If you improve your question, I'll upvote it.  If you leave it as it is I'm going to vote it down because it is a poor question in its current state.

Comment: @zdd: You can't send keys directly from a batch file _if you use VBS_, but you may do that if you use JScript. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836457/how-to-make-a-batch-file-to-run-a-hotkey/22843382#22843382) below...

Answer (score 20):

The original question was tagged `autohotkey`.

You can, indeed, use a batch file to run a autohotkey script.

In your batch file, just run autohotkey and send the path to your script as the parameter.

```
"c:\program files (x86)\autohotkey\autohotkey.exe" "c:\scripts\hotkey.ahk"
```

And in your autohotkey script, do something like this:

```
send ^!1
exit
```

That's it.

Of course, if autohotkey is **installed** on the computer, you could just put a link to the script in your startup folder in the start menu.  That's what I do.

Comment: +1 the only answer that was "loyal" to the "AutoHotkey-tagged" question.

Comment: @bgmCoder, I tried your syntax, but it seems that: 1. I cannot run more than one `*.ahk` scripts through your syntax? (In the command prompt window that gets started, it shall keep displaying the first line that goes in the `*.bat` file; 2. the command window keeps hanging around no matter what.

Comment: Well, if you want to run more than one autohotkey script, you have to put more than one call in the batch file.  Also, in your batch file, you might have to add an `exit` there, too.  I think the batch file will not end until the autohotkey script is complete.  However, there are utilities that will let your batch files be compiled into invisible exe files.  Maybe that can get rid of the black box.  I don't really understand why you need a batch file to run an ahk script though.  Why not just put the ahk file in your startup and forget about the batch file?

Answer (score 4):

The **Batch file** below do what you want:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^%1");
```

For further details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135)

Comment: very elegant, thanks! Beats the VB script solution by not having to set up a second script file.

Comment: Will this be a .bat file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoIt` to create a binary that you can launch in a batch file.

It seems like you tagged `autohotkey` without realising that there is a tool called autohotkey which can probably help you too.