# Batch file that changes URL in open browser

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I've seen something like this:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer (x86)\IEXPLORE.EXE" www.google.com
```

But this just opens a new tab. I would like it to change the whatever website is open to the one listed.

The end goal is to create a batch file that switches between two webpages with a given delay between them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using SendKeys, see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx).

Basically, you look at the dropdown menus of Internet Explorer (i.e. File, Edit etc) and look at the shortcut keys for what you would want to do, then you write a little bit of VBscript to send those keystrokes. You save the VBscript in a file with the ".VBS" extension and then you can just double-click it to run it. Something like this should get you started....

```
 set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.Run "iexplore"
 WScript.Sleep 500
 WshShell.AppActivate "Windows Internet Explorer"
 WshShell.SendKeys "www.google.com"
```

If you have already started IE using your own START command, you can just send the keystrokes you need to control it after that and you will not need the `WshShell.Run` part I have.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. What I'm trying to do is a have a Kiosk setup.

Answer (score 1):

You may use SendKeys directly in your Batch file, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866137/automatically-respond-to-runas-from-batch-file/22870934#22870934) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836457/how-to-make-a-batch-file-to-run-a-hotkey/22843382#22843382) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135) answer; for example:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Start default IE
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer (x86)\IEXPLORE.EXE" www.google.com

:changeLoop
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "keys to change to first webpage"
timeout /T 10
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "keys to change to second webpage"
timeout /T 10
goto changeLoop

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```