# How to press a key with batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am new with batch file, I want to know how to auto press a key from batch file.
I want to make a program that open a browser and press the tab key automatically.

Comment: Batch is not generally an appropriate language for interacting with GUI applications. Take a look into 'SendKeys' in VBS.

Comment: Doubt you can do this in batch: prob's use some weird program or use something else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A search for "batch file sendkeys" and further revision returned this list of answers for similar questions:

- [How to make a batch file to run a hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836457/how-to-make-a-batch-file-to-run-a-hotkey/22843382#22843382)
- [Batch file that changes URL in open browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373209/batch-file-that-changes-url-in-open-browser/23376150#23376150)
- [Press Keyboard keys using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135)
- [Automatically respond to runas from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866137/automatically-respond-to-runas-from-batch-file/22870934#22870934)

The Batch file below do what you want:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
rem Open the browser here
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}");
```

Comment: Do we need anything else in our .bat file when we want to press enter after opening an app other than WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}");