# How to pass key press to batch file using Java code?

Tags: java, batch-file, automation, automated-tests, batch-processing

I want to run batch file using Java. That batch file doesn't require any arguments. But on running it asks to press enter key twice.

How can I do this using Java code?

This is what I have tried in batch. If I can do this in batch that will also work instead of Java

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=C:\Windows\System32\CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

rem Start the other program in the same Window
start "" /B test.bat

%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "exit{ENTER}"
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

This `test.bat` run for some time then asks for key press.

Comment: first , write some java code, secondly show us the java code that does not work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) What have you tried so far?
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

To run a batch file in java

```
import java.lang.Runtime;

Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe", "/c", "path of the bat file");
```

According to your question you want to press enter key twice, to do this you can add code in the batch file to enter whenever required

Example

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

For more details
[How to press a key with batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371406/how-to-press-a-key-with-batch-file)