# automatically press a key at specific time

Tags: keyboard

I want to create an exe file to press a key at specific time using batch file or other programs (for example press ENTER at 2:00 AM)
I'll be appreciated if you introduce a program whit this ability to me even non-free software
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some links for you. What you have to know is:

- [How to press a key with batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371406/how-to-press-a-key-with-batch-file)
- [How to run a batch file at a specific time](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000785.htm)

---

[Edit]

There is a nice program called [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) wich does exactly what you want. There is even a thread opened in the forums, explaining on how to execute the script at a specific time:

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/20166-execute-script-at-specific-time/