# Automatically respond to runas from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, runas

I'm trying to get a batch file to automatically enter the password into the "runas" program, but I can't get it to work. Here's my batch file so far:

```
echo password | runas /user:testuser c:/path/to/my/program.exe
```

However, I get an error saying "unknown user name or bad password". I have also tried:

```
runas /user:testuser c:/path/to/my/program.exe < c:/path/to/file/containing/password.txt
```

This comes back with the same error. Does anyone know a way to do this? What I'm trying to do eventually is get the batch file to read a username and password from a config file, and then start "program.exe" as that user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Batch-JScript hybrid script below do what you want. Save it with .bat extension.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
start "" runas /user:testuser c:/path/to/my/program.exe
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("password{ENTER}");
```

For further details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135)

Comment: Thanks! I had got something working by creating a .vbs script from the batch file, but this also works and is much more succint!