# Open Webpage and Login with Batch file

Tags: batch-file, authentication

I am trying to make a .bat file where it opens up a website and provides the necessary login information. The code I have is:

```
runas /user:domain-name\testname "cmd /c route add https://login.yahoo.com/config /login?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F
@pause
```

This is what I saw someone online using to run a file and provide the domain credentials necessary, so I tried to do this with this .bat file but I was unable to produce the result I am looking for. I replaced the IP address the person was using for their domain with the website address that you use to login to yahoo (assuming DNS would catch it and it would work properly).
Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: The username passed to `runas` is a *windows* username for the `runas` program to use; it is completely unrelated to what you use `runas` to execute (the web browser)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866137/automatically-respond-to-runas-from-batch-file/22870934#22870934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot effort I decided the most simplistic way to come about the solution was to create a VB web browser based off of IE that depending on the site you go to fills in passwords. Then with a

```
start browser.vb
```

I was able to start it, and give parameters as to where I wanted to go.
Hop this helps for anyone who was interested.