# Executing commands in new command prompt window with batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that does a runas and automatically enters the password:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
start "" runas /noprofile /user:myuser cmd
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("password{ENTER}");`
```

(source: [Automatically respond to runas from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866137/automatically-respond-to-runas-from-batch-file))

I would like to execute commands in the new window that opens as a result of the "runas" command. Does anyone know how I might go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 start "" runas /noprofile /user:myuser "cmd /k FirstCommand & SecondCommand & ThirdCommand"
```

See `Command /?` for difference between `/c` and `/k`. FirstCommand etc can be a batch file.

Also before using `SendKeys` use `wscript.appactivate "window title"` to make sure you have the correct window for `sendkeys`.

Comment: `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").appactive("")` on the line before `.sendkeys`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Another question, sorry. Is it possible to use a declared variable for the password?

Comment: No. You have to type it. `/savecred` saves the password so you only type it once, but then anyone can start any program as admin.