# Batch ENTER key function?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Okay, so I am currently trying to write a program in Batch and I want to be able to program the ENTER key to be the button without just simply typing `pause` or `pause>nul` because that will let any key work and i don't want that as an option.

This is what it would normally look like:

`set /p continue=
if %continue% == [ENTER KEY GOES HERE] goto start`

Where I have typed `[ENTER KEY GOES HERE]` is where I obviously want to put the Enter key option to proceed, but I don't know how to do that considering it doesn't to be as simple as

`echo Press 'C' to continue...
set /p continue=
if %continue% == C goto start`

If anyone has any ideas, PLEASE tell me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: is this what u are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file, it sure seems like it based on your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply ask for some input, as in:

```
set /p Var1="Press [ENTER] key to continue."
```

The user will have to press enter to continue.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:  it firstly clears the variable and if enter alone is pressed then it will remain empty.

```
set "continue="
set /p continue=
if not defined continue goto start
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it is:

```
set /p continue=
if [%continue%]==[] goto start
```

This works if nothing is entered.