# WScript SendKeys escape special characters

Tags: batch-file, jscript, wsh

I want to make a bat file that prompt user with a default value. All`s fine, I found a CScript way.

But i have a problem with special characters like pharanteses..

bat file is

```
set "mysql_password="
title MyUniqueTitle
CScript //E:JScript //Nologo "%cscripts_path%\sendkeys.js" "MyUniqueTitle" "&GS)u**,o7,r"
set /p "mysql_password=> Enter new MySQL Password: "
```

and sendkeys.js

```
try
{
    var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');
    var Title = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
    var Message = WScript.Arguments.Item(1);
    WshShell.AppActivate(Title);
    WshShell.SendKeys(Message)
    WScript.Quit(0);
}
catch(e)
{
    WScript.Echo(e);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
WScript.Quit(2);
```

Problem is with WshShell.SendKeys(Message) , here i should use an escape function that put bracets to special characters..

Does anyone know an way to escape Message code from SendKeys?

Thanks!

Comment: The batch escape character is `^` (unless you're escaping a `%`, then you use a second one to escape it).

Comment: What you mean? If i add  ) in bracets like   WshShell.SendKeys(&GS{)}u**,o7,r) will work as it should. So need an way in SendKey method to use an escape rule.

Comment: Here are the valid codes for special characters http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx

Comment: @oriceon Why don't you just escape it when you execute the cscript. `CScript //E:JScript //Nologo "%cscripts_path%\sendkeys.js" "MyUniqueTitle" "&GS{)}u**,o7,r"`

Comment: because it`s a dynamic password. Used one was for example prupose :|

Comment: @oriceon, then use string substitution within the batch file to put the curly braces around the special characters before you execute the cscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the special characters with string substitution in the batch file first.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "password=&GS)+[]+u**,o7,r"

SET "password=!password:)={)}!"
SET "password=!password:+={+}!"
SET "password=!password:[={[}!"
SET "password=!password:]={]}!"

rem Enter the prefill value
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "!password!"
rem Read the variable
echo -----------------------------------------------------------
set /P "password=Please enter your password: "
echo password=!password!
pause
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```