# windows batch, output command from variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

how to build command from variables, for examples `buildcmd.bat`

edit: need output as predfined command not execute it

```
@echo off
set /p VAR1=variables 1?:
set /p VAR2=variables 2?: 
echo python D:\myscript.py %VAR1% %VAR2%
```

output

```
C:\bin>buildcmd.bat
variables 1?: var=aaa
variables 2?: var=bbb
python D:\myscript.py var=aaa var=bbb
C:\bin>
```

expected

```
C:\bin>buildcmd.bat
variables 1?: var=aaa
variables 2?: var=bbb
C:\bin>python D:\myscript.py var=aaa var=bbb
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. May [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857183/how-can-i-run-cmd-from-batch-file-and-add-text-to-line-without-executing/29887523#29887523) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549048/is-there-anyway-to-have-preset-data-for-user-input-in-a-batch-file/23551029#23551029) solve your problem perhaps?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue.

---

```
@echo off
set /p VARS1=variables 1?:
set /p VARS2=variables 2?:

    echo %CD%^>python D:\myscript.py %VARS1% %VARS2%
```

- You entered `%VAR1%` and `%VAR2` instead of `%VARS1%` and `%VARS2%` in the `python` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you

```
set /p VARS1=
```

Then perhaps it would be an idea to use `%VARS1%` as the parameter and not `%VAR1%`