# Batch files: Writing a string on DOS prompt (requires Enter key from user)

Tags: batch-file

Using a .bat file, is it possible to write/send a command to DOS prompt ?

For instance, I want to type DIR command (without executing it) unless user press enter (or maybe he could delete the DIR command and type something else)

> c:>DIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("DIR");
```

For further details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619510/input-with-a-default-editable-string-in-a-bat-by-using-powershell/23622808#23622808)

Answer (score 0):

You can easyly write to the screen and read what user enters on keyboard. But what you ask is *simulating* user keyboard action.

It is of course possible, but not with simple batch command. You will have to use wshshell or powershell for that. Here is an example using PowerShell [A simple PowerShell script to send keys to an application windows|InVista](http://invista.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/a-simple-powershell-script-to-send-keys-to-an-application-windows/).