# How to exit Batch File after execution

Tags: powershell, batch-file, console-application

I am writing a batch file to automatically run some EXE and exit the message comes in console

```
"Press any key to continue .. "
```

The batch file contains following code:

```
D:\\Tethys\\SVN\\build\\vs2010\\ReleaseWin32\\bin\\TethysDatabaseUtility.exe install       D:\Tethys\DatabaseInstaller\DatabaseInstaller\RGTestingUtility.cab "" NDI-LAP-262\SQL2008R2 TestDB-Neeraj N sa Brick@123 /c h:
D:\\Tethys\\SVN\\build\\vs2010\\ReleaseWin32\\bin\\TethysDatabaseUtility.exe install D:\Tethys\DatabaseInstaller\DatabaseInstaller\RGTestingUtilityTestCases.cab "" NDI-LAP-262\SQL2008R2 TestDB-Neeraj N sa Brick@123 
D:\\Tethys\\SVN\\build\\vs2010\\ReleaseWin32\\bin\\TethysDatabaseUtility.exe install D:\Tethys\DatabaseInstaller\DatabaseInstaller\RGTestingUtilityBaseLineData.cab "" NDI-LAP-262\SQL2008R2 TestDB-Neeraj N sa Brick@123
```

The exe using in bat file is a console application and code written

```
installer.run();
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

the above code is requirement so i do not change the code,since that console exe is call some other application also.

Please help to exit installer.

[image]

After adding `echo(|`

I have received following error on `console`.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `echo(|myEXEFile.exe`?

Comment: I have update batch file code please suggests how to write `echo(|myEXEFile.exe`

Comment: `echo(|"D:\Tethys\S...\TethysDatabaseUtility.exe" install ...` The idea is to pipe the CRLF from the `echo` command as the standard input to the console application. Depending on how `Console.ReadKey()` is implemented, it can work or not.

Comment: the message you write in your question does not match the screenshot or the c# code.

Comment: ReadKey() will not work with stdin.  You need to use Console.Read() to read from stdin.

Comment: @MC ND i have tried your code and received an error updated on question.

Comment: Unfortunately piping does not work as `ReadKey` tries to get the handle to the console input buffer and it has been redirected. You need to modify you application code, adding an aditional parameter to handle this cases, or changing the problematic code to something like `if (!Console.IsInputRedirected) Console.ReadKey()` (sorry, .Net 4.5) or add code to handle the error. Or you can use something to send the keystroke to the application, as Keith Hill answers, or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23625920/2861476) i posted a little c code (after the edit). Tested against ReadKey and works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a background job (assuming you're on V2 or higher).  The trick is to use the Windows Forms `SendKeys.SendWait()` method to simulate a key press on the PowerShell window that is waiting for key press. You'll have to either use a delay or you could modify the job script to check for something that indicates the installer is finished. Here's the code:

```
Start-Job {param($id) Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
                      $hwnd = (Get-Process -id $id).MainWindowHandle
                      Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
                      Set-ForegroundWindow $hwnd
                      [Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}') 
           } -ArgumentList $pid > $null
```

I tested this with a simple console app I wrote.  BTW this uses a command from PSCX (PowerShell Community Extensions - http://pscx.codeplex.com) called Set-ForegroundWindow.  The implementation is pretty simple if you don't want to take a dependency on PSCX.