# How can I run cmd from batch file and add text to line without executing?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to make file.bat that should run my jar only when user press enter.
Bat must run and does't execute anything without user press enter.
In cmd should be printed:

```
java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
```

A part from that user could change this.text

How can I do this?

Comment: What operating system is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excuse me. I think that the real goal of this question is: "How to prefill the cmd.exe command-line input with an editable string", so the user may just press Enter key to execute the prefilled input, or edit it in any desired way. I copied the method below from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619510/input-with-a-default-editable-string-in-a-bat-by-using-powershell/23622808#23622808):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
rem Enter the prefill value in the keyboard buffer
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "java -jar crawler-1.0.jar"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: It's unclear what this question is asking, exactly, but this sounds like it's probably what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Echo java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
set /p =
java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
Echo.
pause
```

That way, the program will start **only** if the user hits enter (and not any other key). Also, the window should remain to show the output from the program.

Comment: It close after show output and press enter, It must works until user close window.
Maybe, I bad explained what I need :(
I need the same as cmd work, but with already put text in command line and user could change this text

Answer (score 0):

You can always just echo the command, then pause before running the command, not perfect, but it works:

```
ECHO java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
pause
java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
```

Comment: iIt is good, but after executing cmd closed.
How I  can leave it opened ? desirable with: java -jar crawler-1.0.jar put in it and again waiting for enter pressed?

Comment: just add another pause

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cls
echo java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
echo Press ENTER to continue
pause > nul
<insert command to execute here after user press a button>
```

1. line = standard start of batch-file
2. line = clears the screen so that only your wanted text will appear
3. line = displays the text you wanted
4. line = tells the user what to do (it will actually activate regardless of key entered; you can't choose that) [optional of course]
5. line = regular pause command - > nul does only hide the "press a key" in favour of your 4th line custom message, or no message at all
6. line = enter your desired run code

I can't comment, so answer to comment question is here:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
echo java -jar crawler-1.0.jar
echo Press ENTER to continue
pause > nul
<insert command to execute here after user press a button>
goto start
```

Comment: Then you have to add another pause command after your execute command to display whatever was executed before it returns to start OR move the :start command one step down and each run will stack up on the screen.