# Batch script to open command prompt but not execute the command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can anyone pls suggest me how to create a batch file that would open up the command window but just type the command I have specified. It should get executed only when I hit enter manually. eg., I created the below .bat file:

### test.bat

```
cmd.exe /K "cd D:\Code_Home && D: && cls && dir"
```

Now the problem is that it opens up the command window and lists the directory contents, whereas I just want the dir command to stay there and not list me the directory contents until I manually hit enter. Pls suggest if there is a way to do that

Comment: Just cmd.exe should do the trick...

Comment: He wants the command to be pretyped I think, so it wouldn't

Comment: Try a `pause >nul` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run cmd from batch file and add text to line without executing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857183/how-can-i-run-cmd-from-batch-file-and-add-text-to-line-without-executing)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the accepted answer at [How can I run cmd from batch file and add text to line without executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857183/how-can-i-run-cmd-from-batch-file-and-add-text-to-line-without-executing/29887523#29887523) and slightly adjust it in order to solve this question:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
rem Enter the prefill value in the keyboard buffer
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "cd D:\Code_Home & D: & cls & dir"
cmd.exe
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Further details at the given link.