# is it possible to ctrl + end a file through batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch process to open a bunch of .pdf and .txt files. What i do after is manually ctrl+end all the documents to scroll to the bottom of the page. Is it possible to do this through a batch command ?

Comment: Why would you need to scroll to the bottom of a page in a batch command -- batch command implies no one is looking at it while it runs.

Comment: If it's not impossible, it would be insanely complicated to do this with batch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file

Comment: @MarcB That will work...but, it's not a strictly batch solution. :)

Comment: i am basically using a batch command to help open files instead of manually open them. i need to grab a number at the bottom of the files so thats why i need to control end to the bottom of the page. Ill try out the solution marc suggested.

Comment: If you're wanting a number or line from the end of each file, then using a (bat file) for loop to parse each file might save you a lot of work. There are some command line pdf to text converters around, so you could probably do the same with the pdfs.