# How to send Shortcut Keys using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file, where I automatically press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> every few minutes.
until now I have

```
set /a i=0
:start
if /I %i% GEQ 10 goto :next
%SendKeys% "{^}"
%SendKeys% "{s}"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 300000 > nul
goto :start
:next
```

How can I send them together?

Comment: Does `%SendKeys%` refer to the script from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file?

Comment: Yes! I had the Idea, so I googled for it, and found it there.
But this doesn't send both keys at at once, like the shortcut for saving files!

Answer (score 3):

```
%SendKeys% "^s"
```

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx for the complete list of keys and modifiers for `WshShell.SendKeys`.