# How to change identical line/dir in multiple bat files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I would like to update a line in a few different batch files at the same time.

How would I go about writing something to change multiple identical lines in a file.

Specifically, every week I have a BAT file create a new folder labeled "Week monthdayyear"

I have other BATs that have been made to move files to that new folder throughout the week. Currently the only thing I know how to do is manually change the date in each of the BATs that move files to that folder every week. I would like to have my BAT file that creates the new directory to modify the other BATs and input the new directory.

Example:

Each Bat Contains:

```
    ren "...\Week 4-13-2015\..."
```

I need to change each bat to say

```
    ren "...\Week 4-20-2015\..."
```

This question is related to another question I asked a week ago. I solved the other question if you want to use it as reference for more background information and the actual scripts.
[Can a Batch File Tell a program to save a file as? (If so how)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610034/can-a-batch-file-tell-a-program-to-save-a-file-as-if-so-how/29629090?noredirect=1#comment47424836_29629090)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of inter-program communication, that is, the program that create the new folder every week needs to inform to the rest of programs the name of the *current folder*. You may do that via an auxiliary data file. For example, include this (or similar) line in the program that create the folder:

```
echo Week %monthdayyear%> CurrentWeek.txt
```

... and get the right name in each one of the rest of programs:

```
rem Get the name of the current folder
set /P currentFolder=< CurrentWeek.txt

. . .

ren "...\%currentFolder%\..."
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.