# Switch windows with .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to switch windows at regular intervals automatically between Internet Explorer and a Powerpoint presentation.

I did actually cobble something together but accidently deleted it a while back and now for the life of me can't recreate it.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Batch can't interact with GUIs, so forgive me if I'm skeptical.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to send a keypress to the keyboard like ALT + TAB?

Hava a look at this question [Press Keyboard keys using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file)

Comment: I did start off looking at SendKeys however the machine may have other programs running and I only need to switch between two of them. There is a command to open a window if you define the display name. I ran this twice with a delay and a loop but I can't remember of find the command.

Answer (score 0):

###### Create a start.bat Windows Batch File

cd "Path to Directory"
start alttab.vbs

###### Alt Tab script in VB - Save the file in a directory and replace the path in the batch file

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^%{TAB}"