# Preserving doskey context after pipe, or, and

Tags: cmd, environment, doskey

I have multiple doskeys defined in following fashion:

```
doskey ll=dir $*
doskey grep=findstr $*
doskey make=mingw32-make $*
```

I want to use them in conjunction in one-line commands such as:

```
ll | grep my_folder
```

or

```
make && make install
```

But after first pipe/not/and operator, the doskeys no longer appear to exist since the cmd won't recognize the commands. For example, while single `make` command works, calling `echo hello && make` will tell me the make is not recognized as a command.

Is there a way to preserve the doskey context so I can chain them together as written above?

Also, the same issue applies to running batch files using the doskeys, is there a way to preserve the context for that too?

I've heard about the $T argument of doskey, but I am not quite sure if I understand it.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: DOSKEY is only for interactive use. It does not work in a batch file script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616151/doskey-alias-does-not-work-in-batch-script-windows-7

Comment: This looks like it works, but it somewhat defeats the point of having short commands. `ll | cmd.exe /C findstr "new"`

Comment: @lit thanks for clarification with batch files, however using redirection to new cmd instance does not solve anything as the newly executed cmd does not inherit doskey settings

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue...
Following macro was not handling the section after the <kbd>|</kbd> character:

```
doskey system=systeminfo | findstr /C:"OS"
```

But, the following did:

```
doskey system=systeminfo $B findstr /C:"OS"
```

So, looks like doskey's pipe symbol is $B.