# swap KVM view source via terminal/batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im using windows and have 2 computers and using a KVM (Master View) to switch my mouse and keyboard source.

I wanted to create a batch file or a service that will run at the backgroud.

The service will detect the mouse position on the screen, and when the mouse reachs a certain edge it will virtually click on the kvm to swap source, then the mouse will move smothly between the screens and sources ( i dont mind a small lag i just dont want to physically click the KVM)

I searched an api for windows for KVM and couldnt find any. so i figured i can configure the KVM to do button swapping, then my batch will just virtually click those buttons once the mouse reachs the edge i configured.

can this be done?

Comment: check the documentation for your KVM, if there is a keystroke/combination to switch (or some other method to do it "remotely"). If there is no such possibility, you're lost. No software solution will ever be able to push a physical button on another device. The next steps heavily depends on what your KVM supports, but probably you'll need more than just "batch".

Comment: You can swap the source with keystrokes combination. I just dont know what command i can use to "click" a button. Lets say i configure my KVM to swap a source by clicking twice CTRL. theres a way you "click" CTRL using a batch? the closest thing i found was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file and it doesnt seem to do what its suppose to either