# Make a batch file type something in 2 consoles

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that types "quit" in two console windows. These console windows are hosting a game server each and I want them to shutdown when I use the said batch file.

I tried making a batch file terminating the server-console process but that might damage my server logs and such.

Is there a way for a batch script to type something into two separate cmd-windows and then simulating an 'enter'-push?

Comment: No. You can use the sendkeys method in Vbscript or you would need to use a third party program like AutoHotkey or Autotit.

Comment: Have a look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17050135/6707985) from a different post.

Comment: To synchronise tasks: take a look at the [`waitfor`](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) command...