# error making ALT+a object.SendKeys(string) in .bat file with JScript

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard, jscript

I'm trying to send keystrokes to a program in windows (exactly 7 pro) using .bat files and I have come to this question: [Press Keyboard keys using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file#17050135)

It works really well, but specifically I can't use the ALT key. My idea is to open the notepad.exe and use the ALT button to go the the options in the top menu (archive, edit...). When I use it manually it works, but when I use the code `%SendKeys% "%a"` for example (or only the alt button `%SendKeys% "%"`) it only writes `a` in the notepad, without ALT being pressed. What I'm doing wrong?

How to use SendKeys method: [msdn microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx)

my code:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

::rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

start "" /B C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
timeout 2
%SendKeys% "%a"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: When you want to specify a literal percent sign as a string in a batch script, you have to double the percents.  `%SendKeys% "%%a"`

Comment: omg, such a silly mistake XD. Thanks a lot