# input second username and password in putty using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication, automation, putty

I would like to know how to automate an input of username and password in putty after the initial login was successful.

I have a bat file `connect.bat`

```
@echo off

putty [user]@[host] -pw [password]
```

After I run this, it opens a new putty window and validates the login.

When successful, I am redirected not to the shell but to another login screen. Sample below.

[image]

Then I need to manually input a different username and password by typing the following.

```
[username]
[ENTER KEY]
[password]
[ENTER KEY]
```

To be finally redirected to the host's menu.

I tried the following:

```
echo [username] & [password] | putty [user]@[host] -pw [password] 

putty [user]@[host] -pw [password] < user_pass.txt
putty [user]@[host] -pw [password] -m user_pass.txt
```

but failed, is there a way to perform this via batch/powershell script or should I incorporate another application?

Comment: So it's some X Server application, right? That cannot be PuTTY screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the [Sendkeys method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

rem Start the other program in the same Window
start "" /B putty [user]@[host] -pw [password]

rem Send the additional keys
%SendKeys% "[username]{ENTER}"
ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
%SendKeys% "[password]{ENTER}"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: I tried it but I'm having an error. Should I install or activate some applications?

C:\files>connect.bat

C:\files>if (@CodeSection == @Batch)
C:\files\connect.bat(1, 17) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Conditional com
pilation is turned off

C:\files\connect.bat(1, 17) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Conditional com
pilation is turned off


C:\files>

Comment: Ops! I had a typo! The first IF must have an at-sign before: `@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then`... I already fixed it in the code

Comment: Cool I tested it and it's working, thank you very much!