# Auto reply a command line process in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows command line process with a verbose Y/N confirmation question. I would like the automatically put a "Y" response.
I already tried to execute:

```
echo "y" | sdkmanager "platforms;android-14"
echo y | sdkmanager "platforms;android-14"
```

But this commands don't work as well. Does someone know how can I interact with this command automatically for users?

Comment: It looks ok, try without the space, incase it's the trailing space causing the issue `echo y| sdkmanager`

Comment: It is possible that the program is not reading from `stdin`, but rather "insists" on reading from a keyboard.  If that is true, redirecting from `stdin` will not work.

Comment: You may try the [Sendkeys method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292404/input-second-username-and-password-in-putty-using-batch/43292731#43292731)...