# How to run "Open" window of Notepad++ from Command Prompt?

Tags: cmd, notepad++, windows-xp

As you know, Notepad++ can be run from command prompt.

My question is that how can I run the "Open"(CTRL+O) window from command prompt after running Notepad++?

[image]

Comment: no chance to do this with batch (alone). You need some other language. [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17050135/2152082)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to open the window itself?

Because if you need to open te program. you can do a simple CMD

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

to open and create a file you can do this i think. if you have writing permission in the directory. i cannot test this but i think this is the way to create a file

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe File.txt
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe -openSession <PathToYourFile>
```

Or do you need the Specific window?

Comment: I just want to see "Open" window. I will choose the text file from there.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "C:\YOUR\DIRECTORY\tofile.txt"

or on 32 bit machine

C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "C:\YOUR\DIRECTORY\tofile.txt"

Exclude the quotation marks obviously.

Comment: That's the thing Aaron. I want to open that window from command prompt. After that, I will choose the text file myself from window (not from command prompt).

Comment: yeah unfortunately i dont think its possible since its an embedded process within the program notepad++ itself so it requires Notepad++ resources to be running and cant open it individually, of course i could be wrong

Comment: yeah unfortunately i dont think its possible to run on its own since its an embedded process, what you could try like mentioned above by Stephan is a batch program to do it for you