# Send Windows Key in batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt, sendkeys

I've recently been using the *SendKeys* function using Batch script.

I've understood how to input certain keys into a window, such as the tab key:

```
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
```

Or the backspace key:

```
%SendKeys% "{BACKSPACE}"
```

But I have been trying to input the Windows key without pressing it.

Unfortunately, I do not know what the batch name for it is.
I've tried:

```
WIN
WINDOWS
WINKEY
START
LWIN
```

But none have worked.

I've looked everywhere for this, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not said us where you got the SendKeys solution from, but if it was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050135/778560), then in the same post there is [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/8c6yea83(v=vs.84)) to all SendKeys keys names. And no, there is not a name for the Windows key...

Comment: how do you use the sendkeys method in a shell script? do I have to instantiante sth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to simulate the *windows home logo* in [sendkey's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/sendkeys-statement), howevery this does not mean it's not possible.

If you take a look at the [windows shortcut keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) you will find you can simulate **Open Start** with the following key combinations: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

To simulate this in batch, you can use: `powershell -c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('^{ESCAPE}')` **or in your case:** `%SendKeys% "^{ESCAPE}"`.

As stated in sendkeys:

- "**^**" - Simulates a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key press.
- "**{ESCAPE}**" - Simulates a <kbd>Esc</kbd> key press.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was a shortcut. Also, thanks for formatting my question.

Comment: @ZekeYoung I'm here to help - anytime! `:-)`

Answer (score 5):

You can make a program to simulate winkey being pressed.

**WinKey+R.VB**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module SendWinKey

    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H0
    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UInteger)

       Public Sub Main()    
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LWin), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the left Win key down
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.R), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the R key down
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.R), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the R key
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LWin), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the left Win key
       End Sub
End Module
```

Place on your desktop.

Open a command prompt and type

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%userprofile%\desktop\Win+R.vb" /out:"%userprofile%\Desktop\Win+R.exe" /target:winexe
```

A file called Win+R.exe will appear on your desktop. Move it anywhere into the path.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this in my code for using SendKeys and it works great to automate certain keyboard commands. This just automatically sets the default browser and default photo applications. I know this is a couple years late, but hopefully it help

```
control /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 2000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 3}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 1000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 4000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 3}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 1000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 4000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}"                           >>"%TempVBSFile%"
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
echo Return here once you are done.
echo.
echo ^< Press ANY key to return to the Menu ^> & Pause > NUL)
CLS & Goto :Menu
```

Comment: The question was about sending the *Windows* key () specifically.  Unless I'm missing it somewhere, your example doesn't include that key.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds lol

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED - first create a file .vbs with the code

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`   
WshShell.AppActivate "notepad"
WshShell.SendKeys "^{pgdn}"
```

and after you must call that file from a .bat file

Comment: The question was about sending the *Windows* key () specifically.  Your example doesn't include that key.