# How to switch between Chrome windows in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome

I am writing a powershell script that goes through 3 chrome windows (**not tabs**, these windows are on 3 different monitors) and want to refresh every window.
I cannot figure out a way to switch between windows.

I have the following code:

```
while(1) { # Loop forever
  sleep -Seconds 15 # Wait 15sec
  $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell 
  if($wshell.AppActivate('Chrome')) { # Switch to Chrome
   Sleep 1 # Wait for Chrome to "activate"
   $wshell.SendKeys('{F5}')  # Send F5 (Refresh)
} else { break; } # Chrome not open, exit the loop
}
```

This only refreshes one page. I tried to use

```
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%+{ESC}")
```

to switch between apps, but since there are other open apps it is not possible.

Is there a way to switch between Chrome windows? Haven't found any shortcuts or solutions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your refresh:

```
$wshell.SendKeys('^{%TAB}'); # Performs an Alt + Tab to switch windows
```

Of course this implies ONLY chrome windows are open

Since multiple programs are open you could give this a shot:

```
($wshell.AppActivate((get-process chrome).MainWindowTitle))
```

Comment: Unfortunately since there are multiple open apps, alt+tab does not work. I tried the second line, but it fails with "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

Comment: Can you try it again but without the IF() statement?  I believe I have it working for me but I'm not using an IF condition or loop.  Can't see the loop being the issue though

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a shortcut, try this:

If Chrome icon is on the first place (leftmost) on your taskbar, press `Win + 1` TWICE to switch to the second window, press `Win + 1` three times to switch to the third window.

About emulating `Win` key in Powershell, the simplest way is `Ctrl + Esc`; but it doesn't work as `Win + x` combination. This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51868925