# Open Chrome DevTools Using HTML, JS or JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

I have a local webpage I've been working on (not on a server, just a little .htm file)
From what I can tell, it's not possible to open the Chrome DevTools using any of the following methods

- jQuery: Simulate CTRL+SHIFT+I
- JavaScript: Vanilla impl. of jQ attempt
- HTML DOM: BUTTON or ELEMENT for quick access on click
- HTML OnLoad/OnReady: Open DevTools when page is opened

This is less of a "how can I accomplish this" question and more me looking for a definitive answer "it can't be done" (seeing as all the resources I've found are outdated)

To make a long story short, is it possible to open the DevTools window?
- Open on page load
- Open on element click (legitimate click)
- Open automatically using JS or JQ

Comment: It can't be done

Comment: It can be done by an external utility that sends Ctrl-Shift-i or F12 hotkey via OS event.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not an ideal solution, but definitely a viable one! Can't believe the idea never occurred to me. Any ideas on how to do that for just the specific file? My first thought was a batch and/or vbs file similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file

Comment: If the goal is to do it in the active tab I guess you can check the window's title instead.