# Run a .jsx file using Windows Batch

Tags: powershell, jsx, extendscript

I'm trying to run a Adobe Script in Premiere using Windows Batch.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nothing about this, so I hacked my own solution.

You need to use Windows Batch to:

-Run Premiere

```
@echo off
Start "" "enter path for premiere.exe here"
```

Then I followed this: [Press Keyboard keys using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file)

Here I added

```
TIMEOUT /T 7
```

To wait for Premiere to open,

then

```
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"




rem Start the other program in the same Window
start "" "link for Visual Studio Code" "folder path you want to open" "file path you want to open"
```

next I used the shortcut Ctrl shift A to define a target engine, press premi, then F5. I give it some time, then I stop debugging. All done through bash

```
TIMEOUT /T 2

set /P "=Wait and send a command: " < NUL
ping -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "^+{A}"



set /P "=Wait and send a command: " < NUL
ping -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "premi~"



set /P "=Wait and send a command: " < NUL
ping -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "{F5}"

TIMEOUT /T 5

set /P "=Wait and send a command: " < NUL
ping -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "+{F5}"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```