# BAT file with the option of using UP arrow to repeat command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, input-history

I am troubleshooting a problem with a device keeping a Windows 10 PC awake using the `powercfg -requests` command. I have a BAT file containing the following so it can be run quickly via shortcut with run as admin properties:

```
cmd /k powercfg -requests
```

This works, but in addition to keeping the window open, I'd like to be able to keep sending `powercfg -requests` by hitting <kbd>arrow up</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd> when needed, as would normally happen if I opened a command prompt and typed it manually.

I've searched quite a bit here, and aside from making it repeat automatically,
I haven't found anything other than sending arrow keystrokes *in* a BAT file.

I did see something which implied it might be possible to print the command so it's entered at the prompt
after the command has executed, which would be fine too, but haven't had much luck.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is not a *simple* way...

This works:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
start "" /B cmd /K
timeout /T 1
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "powercfg -requests{ENTER}"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

For a further description on the method used, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135)

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell instead. You can *right click on Desktop > New Shortcut* and paste this then save

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "Add-Content -Path (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath 'powercfg -requests'; Invoke-Expression 'powercfg -requests'"
```

It's better to create a new shortcut because you can [set it to always run as admin](https://superuser.com/q/1153519/241386) although it's still possible to put it in a *.bat/*.ps1 file

You can also shorten it like this

```
powershell -NoE -C "$c = 'powercfg -requests'; ac (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath $c; iex $c"
```

PowerShell is far more flexible and powerful than batch. It also has a **persistent history** so it's far more convenient to use PowerShell. You may not even need this and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search through history for the `powercfg` command just like in bash/zsh